# create ad multidimensional array and display it with a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've a problem with php and foreach...
The first query result like this:

```
while ($row = $s->fetch())
{
    $registration[] = array(
    'id_registration' => $row['id_registration'],
    'discipline' => $row['discipline'],
    'speciality' => $row['speciality'],
    'category' => $row['category'],
    'subcat' => $row['subcat']
    );
}
```

excuse me, I was not very precise...
I have 2 table
- the first has a primary key (id_registration) that identifies the registration
- in the second table there are firstrname and lastname of the athletes which refer to the first table by id_registration.

how can I get all the registrations and the athletes of every registration and print all with one o more foreach loop?

I hope I was clear.

Comment: Can you give an exemple of what is expected please ? hard to see with non-english variables names...

Comment: Use JOIN or create additional query if needed (and cache it then)

Comment: @sihciv Acces the id like this $newid = $iscrizioni[0]['id_gara'] 
//is that what your having a hard time with? its nested. you can loop that array. so try this? .  
So would something like this work?
`foreach($iscrizioni as $k => $v){
  $id = $k['id_gara'];
 //db call using $id 
 $result = mysql_query('SELECT name WHERE id = ' . $id);
return $result; //or echo it how you like
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
$iscrizioni = array();
while ($row = $s->fetch())
{
    $iscrizioni['id_gara'] = $row['id_gara'];
    $iscrizioni['disc'] = $row['disc'];
    $iscrizioni['spec'] = $row['spec'];
    $iscrizioni['cat'] = $row['cat'];
    $iscrizioni['subcat'] = $row['subcat'];
}

pre($iscrizioni);
```